# Grub Installation failed into target

Tags: grub2

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on Windows 10 having created partitions for swap area and root. But when I am installing ubuntu it keeps saying "failed to install grub-efi-amd64-signed" into target. I have tried several times but it keeps saying the same thing and installation fails.
Please help me as how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem when Installing Mint 17.3, Lubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu LTS 16.04 on a 16GB Flashdisk from a live USB.
You see when I created the Live USB, I used rufus making bootable USB, I also tried using Mint's Create Bootable USB tool. Same results, failure to install grub...
The problem was that all these tools were creating the Live USB to be compatible with UEFI boards. Thus when you boot your live USB in UEFI mode, your installer will create GPT disk rather than MBR, and for that you need a dedicated partition where you put /boot/efi.
However I wanted MBR, so I started the computer with my Live USB, opened gparted and erased then formatted my installation target, which like I said earlier was a 16GB Flash disk (I like having a portable OS), when you create the new partitions, **select MBR theme**. After you're done with partitioning your target, install Linux as you would normally do and that dreaded error message won't appear at the end of the installation.
Good Luck